# How to change custom target to default boot target in yocto?

Tags: yocto, systemd

We are currently using yocto and systemd (dunfell). How can I change the default boot target during buildtime to `custom.target`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your image recipe add following line:

```
SYSTEMD_DEFAULT_TARGET = "custom.target"
```